# How do you open GWT Designer and what types of files do you open it on?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt-designer

I have been pouring over [the GWT Designer Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/quick_start) documentation and for the life of me I can't find where it tells you how to actually open the designer inside Eclipse.

I have used Eclipse to create an `EntryPoint` subclass but can't seem to figure out how to open it in the GWT Designer. Is this the wrong type of file to open inside the designer? Either way, specific instructions as to how to do this are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**Edit** - this is a GWT/GAE application, so I have to create a new Web Application Project (that handles both GWT and GAE dependencies, resources & file structure) and then open the GWT Designer from a file inside that project. So for instance the Create New (Web Application) Project wizard created a GWT- and GAE-compliant project with an `EntryPoint` subclass called `MyFirstGWTApp`. **I'd like to open this in GWT Designer somehow.**

Comment: Can you Right Click on the file you want to to view: Open With -> Gwt Designer?

Comment: @user905374 - it turns out that the answer is "yes", however that would require me to know which types of files can even be opened with GWT Designer, as I stated in the title of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using eclipse:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go To Help-->Install New Software
3. Enter ther site for your eclipse version i.e. http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 for version 3.7
4. Select the sdk
5. Install the Designer from this location http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7 in the same way
6. Make a new Gwt project
7. By right clicking on a class file inheriting the Composite Class you will be able to open it with Gwt Designer (Open With--> Gwt Designer)
8. If you still see the code, then on the bottom left of the code file you will see the option to open the designer.

Comment: Thanks @Thanos K. (+1) - please see my two followups underneath Martin's answer - I have the same questions for you! Thanks again!

Comment: If you open an empty class file the designer states that it cannot open an item with no GUI Components. GUI components are all these https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/palettes/gwt_palette and the Composite is the a Widget Wrapper thus a GUI component in itself. If you extend your class by any of these then the designer can open. There is no need for a no-arg constructor, any constructor will do. (c) Trial and error :). The Composite needs the initWidget(Widget w) in it's constructor to work.

Answer (score 1):

It should be used for individual independent gui classes (not entry point). Try creating a single class (.java) which inherits from Horizontal panel, has an default constructor(no parameters). Open this by right click -> gwt designer. This should open the designer for you. Now drag a few items in it and view the result. If this doesn't work then you probably installed the plugin wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Martin (+1) - I am able to open a `HorizontalPanel` subclass in GWT Designer thanks to you! Quick followup: (1) what other kinds of files/subclasses can be opened in GWT Designer, and (2) where in the GWT documentation do they explain how to open GWT Designer as you have explained here? I am curious because I read everything I could find and never once came across any literature that mentioned you have to (a) create a `HorizontalPanel`, (b) make sure it has a no-arg ctor, and (c) right-click it and Open With >> GWT Designer. I'm wondering how you knew how to do this! Thanks again!